# Bootstrap 4 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

When I create a solution in visual studio 2019 for a web application, the project is create with a bootstrap 3, but when I update to bootstrap 4 the project view gets broken, the menu bar appears broken.
Has anyone ever experienced that kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes bootstrap 3 to 4 is a major change. You will need to change some thing. It is probably not vs2019. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Template for asp.net web application update to bootstrap 4: https://github.com/PatrickMcDonald/WebApplication1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a site that I found, that helps.  However, you may need to adjust a few things but this does a lot of the heavy work.  (please read disclaimers on site)

[Bootstrap 3 - 4 converter](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/)